# Русский текст в программах

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Мне приходится писать английскими буквами русские слова в консольных приложениях. Сама программа русская (У мне Visual Studio 2010 express). Подскажите, что нужно сделать для возможности выводить русские буквы?
Заранее спасибо.

Нашел ответ(если кому надо)

```
#include<locale.h>  
int main()
{  
setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
```

Comment: <a href=http://hashcode.ru/questions/42373/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#42550 target=_blank>Ссылка</a>

Comment: Вот именно. Один и тот же вопрос задавать по 100 000 раз... Как-то нехорошо...

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS"); (проверял в Windows 7, а в XP помнится у меня не работадо) обеспечивает **корректный вывод** кириллицы из программы (константы) **как на консоль, так и в файл** (перенаправлял stdout, осталось cp1251 !!!).

Ввод не перекодируется (все равно надо делать руками).

Answer (score 3):

**Способ 1:** используй `wcout`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    wcout.imbue(locale(".866"));
    wcout << L"Привет, Мир!";
}
```

Еще как вариант, можно подключить `<windows.h>` и использовать `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)`
Но у меня в 7ке почему-то этот способ не заработал, влом было разбираться. Но вроде для него надо было еще в настройках проекта какую-то галочку переключить, в общем, используй `wcout`, он и лучше, и работает не только в винде.

---

**Способ 2:**
Вспомнил еще один способ, пожалуй самый простой:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");    
cout << "Привет, Мир!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не надо устанавливать. В идентификаторах разрешена только латиница. А в юникодных строках можно писать любые символы, включая китайские иероглифы.

Пример.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    wprintf(_T("Привет, мир\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

То, что пишется в строках: "Привет, мир" и т.п., должно помещаться внутрь макроса _T() для юникодных строк, а все остальное должно быть латиницей (за исключением комментариев).

Comment: Т.е. всегда писать латиницей??

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: не помогло.я хочу что бы "привет мир" писался по русски

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант.

```
<windows.h>

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out,char* s)
 {
     char buf[512],*p=buf;
     CharToOem(s,buf);
     while(*p)
         out<<*p++;
         return out;
 }
```

Comment: Перегружать глобальный оператор<< для `ostream` - **это зло.**

Comment: Какими могут быть последствия?

Comment: Это реальный метод для вывода в нужной кодировке в Винде.

**CharToOem(from,to)** переписывает char [] буфер в кодировке **cp-1251** (она же ANSI *в ней Вы пишете в редакторе и она в файлах* винды) в char [] буфер преобразуя кодировку в **cp-866** (она же ДОС), которая *применяется в консоли*. 

Обратное преобразование делает функция OemToChar(from,to). У этих функций есть синонимы, которые лично мне проще запомнить (в смысле что во что перекодируется): AnsiToOem и OemToAnsi.

Но с консолью есть одна тонкость - аргументы командой строки, набранные в консоли передаются программе в **cp1251**!

Comment: @OpenGLProgrammer

Потому что глобальные операторы на то и глобальные, что распространяются на все объекты типа `std::ostream`.

*Т.е такой код, например, будет пропускать весь текст, идущий в файл, через `CharToOem`:*


`std::ofstream f("file.out");`


`f << "Text";`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, сработает ли, но можно попробовать, например, если есть вариант в чар массиве на английском в ASCII таблице найти и заменить на русские, ну, например, (это только пример) английская буква А имеет цифру 20, а русская 60. Вы делаете функцию, которой, если дать массив, она заменит 20 цифру на 60, и программа покажет русскую а, но это с оператором cin не провернуть, наверное, не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Компилируя консольные приложения на славном языке программирования C++ постоянно сталкиваешься с проблемой кодировок. Русские буквы выводятся каракулями, а с английскими все в порядке. Дело в кодировках. В консоли Windows используется кодировка OEM. А в самой ОС Windows - ANSI кодировка.

Для избежания проблем с выводом русских букв в консоль мы будем пользоваться функцией CharToOem.

Функция CharToOem преобразует строку в набор символов ОЕМ. Эта функция противоположна функции AnsiToOem. 
Думаю вопрос закрыт :)

Comment: > CharToOem ... противоположна функции AnsiToOem

Да ладно?)

Comment: AnsiToOem  и CharToOem это синонимы

    #define AnsiToOem CharToOemA  
    #define CharToOem CharToOemA

это из winuser.h, обычно подключается из windows.h

Comment: > Компилируя консольные приложения на славном языке программирования C++ постоянно сталкиваешься с проблемой кодировок.
Вы забыли дописать " компилируя и запуская в виндовс. Я когда учил с++, перешел на линукс (где конечно настроил UTF-8), и никаких проблем с кодировками (конечно, некоторый софт все равно творил свои каракули, но консоль, редактор, компилятор, которые есть, работали красиво и слажено).
Поэтому, всем, кто спрашивает меня, какая лучшая IDE для **изучения** с/с++ - я отвечаю - линукс.

Comment: Реально проблема (многими не осознаваемая) в том, что  константы в программе **в одной кодировке**, а данные в консоли или файлах **в другой**.

Comment: @KoVadim, форточник и дельфист в лице меня апплодирует последней фразе и полностью соглашается) 

*Простите, не удержался)*

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как вариант можно использовать _cwprintf, но она есть только в Visual C++.