# Как настроить вывод русского языка в консоли Visual studio?

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-studio, консоль

Как в настройках проекта установить кодировку, что-бы в консоле проект С++ выдавл русские буквы, а не крякозябры. Вариант setlocale - не устраивает, нужно именно в настрйоках. Visual Studio 2010 express

Comment: ответ простой - установите линукс. Там в консоли кириллица работает отлично. Даже особо настраивать не нужно. Правда студия там не заработает.

Comment: Так тут дело не в студии, не в С++, а в виндах.

Comment: если по существу, то нужно поправить настройки консоли. И все. Правда многие программы после этого в консоли будут писать "крякозяблами". Но можно попробовать пофиксить аккуратно.

Answer (score 1):

Открываешь исходник, далее:

```
File->Advanced Save Options->Encoding->Cyrillic (DOS)-codepage 866
```

Если, все-таки, не очень принципиальны настройки, то почитай [Русский текст в программах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43938)