# Почему printf не отображает русский текст в C?

Tags: c, printf

Получается такое:
[image: скриншот программы]

Текст программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Решение степенной ф-ии 2 в степени 2x = 392\n");
    float power=log2(392);
    float x=power/2;
    printf("x = %f\n", x);
    getch();
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Попробовал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/43940/245943 - выдаёт ошибку(

Comment: Да проще всего - наберите в 866 кодировке исходник и не мучьтесь :)

Comment: @Harry Залез (в CodeBlocks) в Settings --> Editor --> Encoding Settings, нет ничего похожего на 866...

Comment: И даже в консоли программы нет 866:) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/245943 ...  "Lucida Console и Consolas справляются со всем, кроме иероглифов", но только не у меня:( хотя шрифт, конечно, изменился.

Comment: Насколько я помню, когда-то в CodeBlocks можно было руками в каком-то файле прописать эту 866 кодировку... Сейчас за давностью лет не скажу точно, где именно, но в каких-то настроечных файлах можно было ее добавить.

Comment: @Harry Помогло такое:  

#include <locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251"); Хотя шапка консоли на-ся яЁюср.exe, когда открывается.